# Proof methods and strategy

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

1. When i want to solve some mathematical equation or problem, i need
   some proof methods and strategy. I know that there are some proof
   methods and strategy such as contradiction, mathematical
   induction , pigeonhole principle, inclusion-exclusion  principle  so on.

   I do not know that whether it is enough. **I want to know all proof
   methods and strategy of mathematics such as
   contradiction,mathematical induction etc.**

   ***Can anyone tell me what is the best book or website where i can learn all
   proof methods and strategy of mathematics ?***

Comment: The book of Proof is pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

Just a comment: you can't expect *anyone* to ever know all proof methods and strategies of mathematics, as the art of mathematics consists to a great extent of understanding a problem well enough to come up with a working method.

However, what I think could be beneficial for you, is to look up a book in the genre of general introductions to higher mathematics, which may illuminate certain things. If you search online you might find some! Example: http://people.whitman.edu/~gordon/higher_math.pdf

Other things to consider could be to read proper textbooks on different suitable subjects. I for one think that the book on Discrete mathematics by Biggs has an excellent pedagocial introduction and structure which could be helpful to you. Another book that left a positive impression on me is *A book of abstract algebra* by Charles Pinter, which might be the best math book I've read in terms of readability.

Comment: At first, i want to know basic proof methods and strategy. Then high level.

Comment: The methods described *are* basic.

Comment: oh i see. thanks a lot.

Comment: It's just that the idea to even care about proof strategies and such is considered "higher mathematics", because it is more "high-level" than to just multiply numbers and differentiate polynomials and such. I think it can be a misleading name, but people call it that.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to work through ***How to Prove It: A Structured Approach***, by $\underline{\mathrm{Daniel\; J. \,Velleman}}.$

I have a copy, in paperback, 2nd edition (2006). I can't tell you how many folks to whom I've recommended this book.  (BTW  I am not the author of the text!.) Compared to a lot of textbooks, this is a "steal" (relatively cheap and very high quality.)

I've found the pdf of of the complete  book published on a faculty web-page for students to have access: [***How to prove it***, Velleman](http://users.metu.edu.tr/serge/courses/111-2011/textbook-math111.pdf). Look at the table of contents to see what you can learn with the text.

Note: Learning proof strategies requires far more than *knowledge about proof strategies.* You'll need to complement your studies "about" proofs with practice "doing proofs," of all kinds, in different contexts.

Comment: thanks a lot for suggest me.